# JavaCV - strange black screen when playing a file with FFmpegFrameGrabber

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, javacv

I am using JavaCV and it's FFmpegFrameGrabber in my project. It loads and player files OK, when I launch the project from Eclipse, but shows either a black screen or a still 1st frame when I run a compiled project. Sometimes comming with this error:

```
Input #0, avi, from 'C:/path/Start_Cut.avi':
Duration: 00:00:20.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 26002 kb/s
Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1920x1080, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Cannot allocate memory. com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber$Exception: Cannot initialize the conversion c ontext.
            at com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.jav a:280)
```

and sometimes with

```
[mpeg4 @ 6A95DF20] Invalid and inefficient vfw-avi packed B frames detected
Input #0, avi, from 'C:/path/Start_Cut.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:20.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 26002 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 1920x1080 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 30
 tbn, 25 tbc
```

does anyone has a clue on this?

**UPDATE:**

I have been able to narrow down the problem. For some reason, FFmpegFrameGrabber returns `null` upn calling the `grab()` method. Why does it work in Eclipse and does not work in standalone build? All libraries are included and I suppose, it would come up with an error if they did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the 2.4.0 version of OpenCV and to the current version of JavaCV did the trick. If someone gets in the same situation (which is unlikely), just perform a brand new installation following the instruction on the JavaCV website.